# Error Mounting Azure Data Lake in Apache Spark using Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying mount our Azure Data Lake with the following Python code in Apache Spark

```
def check(mntPoint):
  a= []
  for test in dbutils.fs.mounts():
    a.append(test.mountPoint)
  result = a.count(mntPoint)
  return result

mount = "/mnt/lake"

if check(mount)==1:
  resultMsg = "<div>%s is already mounted. </div>" % mount
else:
  dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://root@adlsprexxxxxdlsdev.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = mount,
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.adlspretxxxxdlsdev.blob.core.windows.net":""})
  resultMsg = "<div>%s was mounted. </div>" % mount

displayHTML(resultMsg)
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storage Key is not a valid base64 encoded string.
```

The full error is as follows:

```
ExecutionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3313750897057283> in <module>
      4   resultMsg = "<div>%s is already mounted. </div>" % mount
      5 else:
----> 6   dbutils.fs.mount(
      7   source = "wasbs://root@adlsprexxxxxxxkadlsdev.blob.core.windows.net",
      8   mount_point = mount,

/local_disk0/tmp/1619799109257-0/dbutils.py in f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
    322                     exc.__context__ = None
    323                     exc.__cause__ = None
--> 324                     raise exc
    325             return f_with_exception_handling
    326
```

Can somene point me to what to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide storage key, while right now you have the empty string.  Usually people put the storage key into the Azure KeyVault (and mount it as secret scope) or use Databricks-baked Secret Scope, and then access that storage key via `dbutils.secrets.get` (as it's shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--mount-an-azure-blob-storage-container)):

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://root@adlsprexxxxxdlsdev.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = mount,
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.adlspretxxxxdlsdev.blob.core.windows.net":
      dbuitils.secrets.get(scope_name, secret_name)})
```